# yii mssql query not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii

I have the following query:

```
Yii::app()->dbNav->createCommand()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('dbo Spectrum Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header')       
    ->where('"Log Number" = :id', array(':id'=>$_GET['lognumber']))
    ->queryRow();
```

And it is failing with the following error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Invalid object name 'dbo'. [20018] (severity 5) [(null)]. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT *
FROM [dbo] [Spectrum Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header]
WHERE "Log Number" = :id
```

My dblib connections works with mssql. I am trying to convert the following to yii

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM [Spectrum Geo Limited\$Purch_ Inv_ Header] WHERE [Log Number] = $q ";
```

In Management studio I run the following to get the required result:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
  FROM [Navision].[dbo].[Spectrum Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header]
    where [Log Number] = 4593
```

The following works but is this ideal way to do it?

```
Yii::app()->dbNav->createCommand("SELECT * FROM [Spectrum Geo Limited\$Purch_ Inv_ Header] WHERE [Log Number] = ".$_GET['lognumber'] );
```

**FURTHER**

If i do the following

```
Yii::app()->dbNav->createCommand()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('[dbo].[Spectrum Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header]')
        ->where('"Log Number" = :id', array(':id'=>$_GET['lognumber']))
        ->queryRow();
```

I get following error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header]
WHERE "Log Number" = '4593''. [20018] (severity 5) [(null)]. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT *
FROM [[dbo]].[[Spectrum] [Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header]]
WHERE "Log Number" = :id
```

Now I have tried :

```
Yii::app()->dbNav->createCommand()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('[Spectrum Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header]')
        ->where('"Log Number" = :id', array(':id'=>$_GET['lognumber']))
        ->queryRow();
```

with the error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header]
WHERE "Log Number" = '4593''. [20018] (severity 5) [(null)]. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT *
FROM [[Spectrum] [Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header]]
WHERE "Log Number" = :id
```

Removal of where clause gives this error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header]'. [20018] (severity 5) [(null)]. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT *
FROM [[Spectrum] [Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the brackets around the table name because the table has spaces in its name.

Generally that is considered poor design, but looks like this is a database from a 3rd party vendor, so you may not be able to change it.

Edit: you may not need the [dbo] either ...

Edit 2: it's the space in your column name in your where clause that is causing issues now.

Edit 3: If you look at your original query that works:

```
Yii::app()->dbNav->createCommand("SELECT * FROM [Spectrum Geo Limited\$Purch_ Inv_ Header] WHERE [Log Number] = ".$_GET['lognumber'] );
```

and then compare it to this:

```
SELECT * FROM [[Spectrum] [Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header]]
```

you'll notice that you have your brackets different.

Use this and it should work:

```
SELECT * FROM [Spectrum Geo Limited\$Purch_ Inv_ Header]
```

Edit 4:

Ok, what happens if you use the following?

```
Yii::app()->dbNav->createCommand()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('Spectrum Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header')       
    ->where('"Log Number" = :id', array(':id'=>$_GET['lognumber']))
    ->queryRow();
```

I'm leaving out the `dbo.` part as your SQL statement worked before without it.  By leaving all the spaces in there, we may active the Yii auto bracketing that was causing you headaches earlier ...

Comment: I wanted to know if I can get it to work like using `Yii::app()->dbNav->createCommand()
        ->select()
        ->from()
        ->where()
        ->queryRow();`, instead of putting the whole statment in 1 line

Answer (score 0):

When i tried this its works for me:

```
$row=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('*')
->from('wdr_user')
->where('id = :id', array(':id'=>135))
->queryRow();
print_r($row);
```

I hope if you remove double quotes inside the where clause it should work.

Comment: my one has a space in the column, so it needs the double clause?